# C# - Creating array where the array value has multiple objects and each one has a value too

Tags: c#, arrays

I have just recently been doing something in C#, i would like to know how to do something like this.

```
Array[0] =
  Array['Value'] = 2344;
  Array['LocationX'] = 0;
  Array['LocationY'] = 0;
Array[1] =
  Array['Value'] = 2312;
  Array['LocationX'] = 2;
  Array['LocationY'] = 1;
Array[2] =
  Array['Value'] = 2334;
  Array['LocationX'] = 4;
  Array['LocationY'] = 3;
```

The data it self its not important, the thing is that i know how to do this in PHP. But in C# i don't, and I've tried some ways and no luck.

In PHP i could just do something like this:

```
$Array[0]->Value = 2344;
$Array[0]->LocationX = 0;
$Array[0]->LocationY = 0;
```

And those values would be added to the Array.

In C# i've tried this and doesn't work that way.

Could someone enlighten me in how to do this in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the data structure?

Comment: A for loop would go to every element in another array. Do some filtering and then add to this array. Nothing special just those 'hello worlds' needed to understand arrays. And once I'm learning C# and don't know how to do this, i thought you guys could help out.

Comment: We still don't know what you want to do. Arrays are not ends in themselves.  Just means to accomplish things like calling a function or outputting data to a web page.  ASP.Net has better constructs than arrays for both of those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could have an array of instances of a class that you write like so:

```
public class DataForArray
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int LocationX { get; set; }
    public int LocationY { get; set; }
}
```

Then something like this:

```
DataForArray[] array = new DataForArray[10];
array[0] = new DataForArray();
array[0].Value = 2344;
etc...
```

Answer (score 5):

Either write a class or struct to hold Value, LocationX and LocationY.

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo(value, x, y)
  {
    Value = value;
    LocationX = x;
    LocationY = y;
  }

  Foo() {}

  int Value;
  int LocationX;
  int LocationY;
}

Foo[] f = new [] 
{
  new Foo(1, 2, 3), 
  new Foo(2, 3, 4)
}
```

or alternatively initialize the array this way:

```
Foo[] f = new [] 
{
  new Foo() { Value = 1, LocationX = 2, LocationY = 3 },
  new Foo() { Value = 4, LocationX = 5, LocationY = 6 },
}
```

Or use an Array of `Dictionary<string, int>`.

```
Dictionary<string, int>[] array = new []
  {
    new Dictionary<string, int>() {{ "Value", 1 }, {"LocationX", 2}, {"LocationY", 3 }},
    new Dictionary<string, int>() {{ "Value", 4 }, {"LocationX", 5}, {"LocationY", 6 }}
  }
```

Which is only recommended if it needs to be dynamic (means: you want to have different values in each element of the array or your keys are in strings, not known at compile-time.) Unless it is just hard to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

in C#, you can try something like this

```
// initialize array
var list = new[]
               {
                   new {Value = 2344, LocationX = 0, LocationY = 0},
                   new {Value = 2312, LocationX = 2, LocationY = 4},
                   new {Value = 2323, LocationX = 3, LocationY = 1}
               }.ToList();

// iterate over array
foreach (var node in list)
{
    var theValue = node.Value;
    var thePosition = new Point(node.LocationX, node.LocationY);
}

// iterate over array with filtering ( value > 2300 )
foreach (var node in list.Where(el => el.Value > 2300))
{
    var theValue = node.Value;
    var thePosition = new Point(node.LocationX, node.LocationY);
}

// add again
list.Add(new { Value = 2399, LocationX = 9, LocationY = 9 });
```

Comment: @Hellfrost: that's true, but it is very close to the php implementation. There is even a bit more type safety as using duck types.

Comment: @Hellfrost: no it's not.  It's absolutely clear and absolutely defined and absolutely uses static typing.  This is not dynamic typing.  This is not "duck typing" either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymous type in C# like that:

```
var arr = new[] {
    new{Value = 1, LocationX = 2, LocationY = 3},
    new{Value = 1, LocationX = 2, LocationY = 3},
    new{Value = 1, LocationX = 2, LocationY = 3},
    new{Value = 1, LocationX = 2, LocationY = 3},
    new{Value = 1, LocationX = 2, LocationY = 3} };
```

Only one problem is that properties in anonymous type are read-only. So You can't do something like that:

```
arr[1].Value = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that details the use of Multidimensional arrays

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(VS.71).aspx